# how to post a dummy json response to the server without adding it to database using Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, aiohttp

im trying to figure out is there any way to create post json response  to the server without adding it to database

tried using APIView but that didnt work with my code

```
async def index(request):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        data=await(email_sending(client))
        print(data)
        await client.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/acc/signup/',data=data)
        return web.Response(text="OK")

async def email_sending(client):
    async with client.get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c23aef12f00003300049691') as resp:
        resp=await(resp.json())
        totp = pyotp.TOTP('base32secret3232')
        otp=totp.now()
        smtp.sendmail("you@gmail.com",resp['email'], otp)

        # await asyncio.sleep(30)

        sucess=asyncio.create_task(email_verification(otp,client))
        # await sucess
        return resp


async def email_verification(otp,client):
    async with client.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/connect/hello/') as v_otp:

        v_otp=await(v_otp.json())
        print(v_otp)
```

here you can see from the following code it gets email adress and username from   another server as json and then sends an otp to that email and now i want to use django rest framework to create a temporary json response for that email_verification step so that i can verify that email (but as of now the code just prints the response)

here is what i have tried earier

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return Response({"message": "Got some data!", "data": request.data})
    return Response({"message": "Hello, world!"})

# class hello_world(APIView):
#     def post(self, request):
#         # if request.method==POST:
#             otp=request.data
#             return Response({'otp':otp})
```

but couldnt figure out how to make it happen

Comment: If you switch to [generic views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) you'll be able to override `perform_create ` to call `serializer.save()` conditionally.

Comment: sorry , i ididnt get you .Please can you make it clear

Comment: Can you clarify what response you expect, please?